# Excel VBA Adding records below existing values

Tags: vba, excel

I've been developing a little tool that query's our database and returns some references.

I'm having a problem adding the newly query'd values below already existing values in the excel `Sheet1`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Ref As String
Const DWConnectString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB... "

Public Property Get rRef() As String
    rRef = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Ref = Trim(rRef)
End Property

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim rRef As String
    rRef = Me.TextBox1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub ZoekRef_Click()
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim cm As Object
    Dim Ref As String
    Dim StrSource As String
    Dim startrow As Integer

    Ref = rRef

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open DWConnectString

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    'rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    StrSource = "Select CONSIGNMENT.CONSIGNMENT, CONSIGNMENT.DOCUMENT_REMARK_2, INVOICE_HIST.NET_AMOUNT, INVOICE_HIST.VAT_AMOUNT, INVOICE_HIST.INV_CURRENCY "
    StrSource = StrSource & "from CONSIGNMENT  left outer join INVOICE_HIST  ON CONSIGNMENT.CONSIGNMENT=INVOICE_HIST.CONSIGNMENT "
    StrSource = StrSource & "where DOCUMENT_REMARK_2 like '%"
    StrSource = StrSource & Ref & "%'"

    rs.Open StrSource, cn

    If rs.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Geen Resultaten"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim fieldNames, j

        rs.MoveFirst

        ReDim fieldNames(rs.Fields.Count - 1)

        For j = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            fieldNames(j) = rs.Fields(j).Name
        Next

        Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Value = fieldNames

        For j = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
            Sheet1.Columns(j).AutoFit
        Next

        Sheet1.Cells.CopyFromRecordset rs
        'fldcount2 = Sheets("sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        Sheet1.Rows(1).Insert
        Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Value =   fieldNames
        startrow = 3

        Do Until rs.EOF
            rs.MoveNext
            startrow = startrow + 1
        Loop
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

I thought about using the line:

```
Do until trim(cells(startrow,1).Value) = "" 
    startrow = startrow + 1 
Loop
```

Before the `rs.Movenext` lines, but that seems to test the recordset, not the actual excel file.

Can I test my current Sheet1's values before adding the new recordset so it comes below what's already existing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the last line with data? There are [plenty of ways](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) to do so, my favorite being `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: So in which part of my code do I add this line + use the lastrow so that I copy my RS in the right place?

Comment: I couldn't tell by looking at your code, are you trying to select a range of rows? Or are you just trying to get the first open row at the bottom and then paste data below it?

Comment: the first open, but don't worry, I got it to work! My code needed some thinning out, I found a way to check my existing values in the excel. Thanks though!

Comment: Sure thing! If you answered your own question, could you post the solution in an answer below and then accept your own answer? Just in case someone down the road is having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the scope of your loop.

```
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF

   'Do all your work here


   'Then increment your counter and the recordset
    rs.MoveNext
    startrow = startrow + 1
Loop
```